# Azure SQL view contents of secondary (Geo-Replicated) Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure, database-replication

I have set up an Azure database instance which supposedly replicates into a 'read only' secondary database using standard geo-replication. In the Azure portal I can see the status of the replication is 'online' and 'Secondary type' is 'Offline', which appears to be normal.

My question is, is there a way for me to see the actual contents of the secondary database, to ensure the replication is actually working as planned?

I cannot 'Manage' the database in the portal. I can connect to the instance in SQL Management Studio, where I can see the database but expanding tables / stored procedures shows nothing (a bit like connecting to a secure database using the non-secure connection string). I am also not able to run any queries against it as it gives me 'Connection to an offline secondary database is not allowed.'

I've searched this site an did a web search for an answer but can't seem to find one. Am I supposed to blindly rely on the fact that Azure is perfoming the replication correctly (with no way to double-check), or am I missing something here?

Many thanks in advance for any light you are able to shed on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Geo-Replicated Secondary DBs are offline copies that do not accept client connections (so there is no way to query the data directly). If you need a readable Geo-Replicated Secondary then you must use the Active Geo-Replication available for Premium DBs.

Even though you can't query Standard Geo-Replicated DBs directly, you can use the DMVs in the Master to determine if the continuous copy is working correctly.

On the Master try the following:
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_database_copies
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_Continuous_copy_status

I hope this helps!

For more information about Standard Geo-Replication, Active Geo-Replication Or Checking the activity of continuous copy use the following links.

- Standard Geo-Replication: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/Dn758204.aspx
- Active Geo-Replication: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741339.aspx
- Continuous Copy DMV Blog: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/pie-in-the-sky/2014/12/25/monitoring-geo-replication-in-sql-azure-using-dmvs/

Comment: Good answer, thanks, but still confused about a couple of points about our set up. My primary database's dashboard indicates it is set up for Active Geo-Replication, and lists the secondary database correctly. So according to the docs you linked to I should have read-only access(?).
This is despite being standard tier databases which shouldn't allow for Active Geo-Replication.
Also, I have an entry in view dm_database_copies but nothing at all in dm_Continuous_copy_status, which would indicate the copying is not actually happening, so I still have no idea whether replication is taking place?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to repro your situation and I think I understand the confusion. 
When the Secondary Type = "Offline" then it is a standard Geo-Replicated Secondary. The Primary Databases page is confusing, but when you click on the link to the secondary should show that it is offline.

As far as understanding if the continuous copy is working, run the script below against the Primary (I was mistaken last time, Sorry). 
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_Continuous_copy_status

You should see the linked server, database, and Replication State.

As before if you need to read from your secondary, you will have to created a premium active-Geo Replicated Secondary.

Hope This helps!

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. I was running that query against the master database on my primary instance, running it against the database itself produces 1 result as expected. I'm a bit concerned at having NULL in the last_replication field though.